# Foundation Centering issue

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I am trying to build online web app using foundation and I have issue about centering 2 large-6 columns sharing 1 row. I have strange GAP between my 2 element containers (the gap is marked in RED). How can I put those elements close each other without having this gap or do you have why I have this gap ?  I am not sure but I think the last column from foundation is floated to the right and thats why those 2 elements have this gap. Any clue on this ?
[PIC example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDpH8.png)

```
 <div class="mainHeader">
      <div class="wrapper">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="large-6 columns one">
          <div class="leftSide">
            <img src="img/sun.png" width="142"  height="142" title="someText" alt="someText">
          </div><!-- end leftSide -->
        </div>

        <div class="large-6 columns one">
          <div class="rightSide">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- end row -->

      </div><!-- end wrapper -->
    </div><!-- main header -->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="small-12 large-6 columns text-center">
```

Comment: The "text-center" class will align the images in the center of the <div>.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `text-left` and `text-right` like this:

```html
<div class="mainHeader">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-6 columns text-left">
        <img src="img/sun.png" width="142" height="142" title="someText" alt="someText">
      </div>
      <div class="large-6 columns text-right">
        <img src="img/sun.png" width="142" height="142" title="someText" alt="someText">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```